# Remove page link/number from table of contents for Part, make it centered and name in new line

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, titletoc

I am trying to reproduce the format of table of contents shown here:

[image]

My attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft,titletoc}

%\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2em}
%\cftsetindents{subsection}{0em}{2em}
\usepackage{theanomodern}
\usepackage[baskerville]{newtxmath}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centerline{\Large CONTENTS}~\\[-1.5cm]}}

\titlecontents*{chapter}[0pt]{}{\textsc{\chaptername} \thecontentslabel:\quad}{}{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linktoc=none,}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \clearpage
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\centering{}Chapter I}
    \part{One}
    \chapter{The Greatest Common Divisor of Two Numbers}
    \part{Two}
    \chapter{Prime Numbers and Factorization into Prime Factors}
    
\end{document}
```

The output is a little close but not quite. Missing features:

1. Part and the label does not start with Part. For this I already tried modifying with `\titlecontents` but got error so removed it from MWE.
2. Parts are centered
3. Parts do not have any link to page at the end
4. Name of parts are on separate line
5. Chapter names are aligned which is not in my output

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, \part does not use \numberline for the part number, which makes reformatting difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution does not use tocloft.

The tricky bit was separating the part number from the title in the hyperlink.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\usepackage{theanomodern}
\usepackage[baskerville]{newtxmath}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centerline{\Large CONTENTS}~\\[-1.5cm]}}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}{\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}%
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}#1}}{}{FAILED}%

\newcommand*{\@partnumber}{}% reserve global name

\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \begingroup
      \def\numberline##1{\xdef\@partnumber{##1}}%
      \setbox0=\vbox{\centering\bfseries\strut #1}% Could be more than one line
      \centering
      \leavevmode
       \hyperlink{\Hy@tocdestname}{\large \partname~\@partnumber}\\
       \usebox0
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
  
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{% #1 = title, #2 = pagenumber
\begingroup
  \def\numberline##1{\hbox to \@tempdima{\chaptername~##1:\hfill}}% add \chaptername
  \@dottedtocline{0}{0pt}{3cm}{#1}{\hyperlink{\Hy@tocdestname}{\bfseries #2}}% 3cm is the space reserved for the chapter number box
\endgroup}
 
\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linktoc=none,}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \clearpage
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\centering{}Chapter I}
    \part{One}
    \chapter{The Greatest Common Divisor of Two Numbers}
    \part{Two}
    \chapter{Prime Numbers and Factorization into Prime Factors}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add dots until the page number comes and align the titles of chapters?

Comment: Easier than doing it the previous way.