# How to Align part number to the right and part name to left, in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, align, titletoc

I need to align the roman number to the right, to maintain part names vertically aligned

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{ paperwidth = 16 cm,
 paperheight = 23 cm,
 outer=10mm,
 inner=15mm,
 top=20mm,
 headsep=4mm,
 bottom=20mm
 }
 \usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{part}[-.8em]
{\vspace{0.25cm}}
{}
{}
{\fontsize{17}{8}\selectfont\dotfill\rlap{ \  \hfill\contentspage}}
[]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part[PARTE I]{{\color{gray}ЧАСТЬ I}\\\fontetitulos\fontsize{150}{15}\selectfont PARTE I}

\part[PARTE I]{{\color{gray}ЧАСТЬ I}\\\fontetitulos\fontsize{150}{15}\selectfont PARTE I}
\part[PARTE I]{{\color{gray}ЧАСТЬ I}\\\fontetitulos\fontsize{150}{15}\selectfont PARTE I}
\part[PARTE I]{{\color{gray}ЧАСТЬ I}\\\fontetitulos\fontsize{150}{15}\selectfont PARTE I}
\part[PARTE I]{{\color{gray}ЧАСТЬ I}\\\fontetitulos\fontsize{150}{15}\selectfont PARTE I}
\part[PARTE I]{{\color{gray}ЧАСТЬ I}\\\fontetitulos\fontsize{150}{15}\selectfont PARTE I}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How or where is `\fontetitulos` defined? A separate question: What are you hoping to achieve by consistently setting the second argument of `\fontsize` to be much smaller than the first?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643190/remove-page-link-number-from-table-of-contents-for-part-make-it-centered-and-na

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the answer you are hoping for but I can't compile your MWE because it returns

```
Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \fonttitulos
```

However you could try using the `tocloft` package like

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftpartnumwidth}{4em}
```

which would normally increase the space in the ToC allotted for part numbers. I can't process your MWE with this addition and maybe what other things you have in your MWE would not work with this.